# Count skipped cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I'm aware of IF BLANK and COUNTA but I can't quite get what I'm after which is to have a formula (not VB script) to count the number of skipped cells in a column.
   For example I have

```
a1: 10
a2: 12
a3: 15
a4: 14
a5: 16
a6: 17


b1: 8
b2: 10
b3: 12
b4:
b5: 8
```

Column b is being filled in by myself and I want to count the number of deliberately skipped cells, starting at the top. In this case for col b this would be 1 (b4). And yes, b6-b999 are all blank but I don't want to count them. Any ideas?

Comment: Why does B6 not count?

Answer (score 0):

The formula you are looking for is `COUNTBLANK`

But I can't really think of a formula extracting the blank cells at the end (b6-b999)

**edit** I've created an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) which should suit your needs:

```
=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(B1,0,0,MAX((B:B<>"")*ROW(B:B))-ROW(B1)+1))
```

Remember - thats a **array formula**! You have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm it after you've entered it!

Comment: Will this account for the last item in column A being blank in column B? Or should you max(A:A)?

Comment: This will only count the empty cells in column B. For Column A you would have to either copy above formula and adjusted it for column A, or rewrite the formula. The easiest way to take both columns into account would be `=(COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(B1,0,0,MAX((B:B<>"")*ROW(B:B))-ROW(B1)+1)))+COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(A1,0,0,MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(A:A))-ROW(A1)+1))`

Comment: No, the question is if the *last* cell in column B is blank (skipped) - will it be counted?

Comment: No it won't with above formula. Let me create an realistic example, wherein you it would take that into account.

Comment: If A1:A10 are used and B2 and B10 are blank, your formula gives `1`. If you change it to `=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(B1,0,0,MAX((A:A<>"")*ROW(B:B))-ROW(B1)+1))` it gives 2, the number of skipped cells in B where A has a value.

Comment: For your example the correct code would be `=COUNTBLANK(OFFSET(B2,0,0,MAX((A:B<>"")*ROW(A:B))-ROW(B2)+1))`
Result picture: http://i.imgur.com/ENtza65.jpg Formula picture (german formula, sorry, got a german excel client) http://i.imgur.com/7gUYJbQ.jpg

Comment: Using entire column references within an array formula is not at all advisable. If, for example, there is only data up to row 100, then that formula is being forced to calculate 1048476 more cells than are actually necessary, an astonishing amount for a single formula.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to count the skipped cells in column B excluding B6 use:

```
=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("B1"&":B"&MATCH(9.9E+307,B:B,1)))
```

If you wish to count skipped cells in column B relative to completed cells in column A then:

```
=COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("B1"&":B"&MATCH(9.9E+307,A:A,1)))
```